# Can't scroll using the touch screen on iOS devices within vim

Tags: ios, terminal, vi

Over the past days I've started to do my day-to-day (development) work on my iPad instead of the MacBook. I have the MacBook Pro always online and available to connect to over ssh but have a problem with vim over ssh (and screen, but without screen the behavior is the same). Whichever Terminal App I've tried, I couldn't get mouse scrolling to work with the touch screen. If I use another computer to connect to the MacBook, I can scroll through my code with the mouse or the touchpad (with `set mouse=a`). No luck on the iOS devices though. I think it's not a problem with the app as I've tried about each and every major terminal app for iOS that I can think of. Termius, Prompt 2, Blink each didn't provide me with a way to scroll through files using my finger.

For me, the primary question is: Is this even possible or am I wasting time here?

Comment: How do you want to initiate scrolling on an iPad?

Comment: I hoped to have the same gesture available that I use to scroll the “normal” terminal output. If I use finger swiping up and down it seems to do the same thing that the mouse wheel does in the terminal on a Mac. If I use the wheel in Terminal running vi(m), it scrolls through the open file.